# How to use clickonce deployment for a VSPackage

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a VSPackage project and I need to use clickonce to deploy it but there is no option to deploy in the solution explorer menu in VS 2008. How can I deploy the VSPackage using clickonce ?

Answer (score 0):

ClickOnce is simply not a possible deployment solution for VSPackages. In Visual Studio 2010, there is the notion of a VSIX enabling simple deployment (it's basically just a zip file + metadata).

For Visual Studio 2008, you can use a '.vsi' file, but this doesn't support VSPackages (only addins).